# How to use JQV map in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to create a JQV country map for my dashboard. I have a Customer model and this model has a country field. This field is connected with a foreign key and I can get country codes and JQV map is accepting country codes.

I created an array in my views and when I print it works. But when I put in the data field of the map chart, does not show anything.

How can I fix it?

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
...
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)


class Country(models.Model):
...
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

**views.py**

```
def approval_context_processor(request):

   ...
        countries_iso = Customer.objects.values_list('country__country_code', flat=True).distinct()
...
        for cn in countries_iso:
            arr.append(cn)
        print(arr) // it works truely.

    else:
        pend_list = 0
        submit_list = 0

    context = {
        ...
        'arr': arr
    }

    return context
```

**dashboard.html**

```
...
<div class="mapcontainer">
   <div id="map-example" class="vmap" style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>

<script>

    var country_list = []

    {% for country in arr %}
        country_list.push( '{{ country }}' )
    {% endfor %}

    window.alert(country_list) //It works truely

        $('#map-example').vectorMap(
        {
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth: 2,
            color: '#e4e4e4',
            enableZoom: true,
            hoverColor: '#35cd3a',
            hoverOpacity: null,
            normalizeFunction: 'linear',
            scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
            selectedColor: '#35cd3a',
            selectedRegions: country_list,
            showTooltip: true,
            onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
            {
                return false;
            },
            onResize: function (element, width, height) {
                console.log('Map Size: ' +  width + 'x' +  height);
            },
        });
    </script>
```

This is how it looks:
[image: map]

Comment: Hi , remove `[]` from `[country_list]` see if that works .

Comment: I tried it but didn't work